# Extracting or copy files from local to remote via FTP

Tags: php, ftp

I have a FTP connection (Dont have any .ppk)

I have a zip file in my remote, which needs to be extracted in the remote itself. or the extracted zip folder needs to be copied from local to remote.

I tried this:

```
scp -i -P 21 Folder_name/* user@hostname:/public_html/destination_remotefolder
```

But this throws:

> Warning: Identity file -P not accessible.

I also tried:

```
scp -r /cygdrive/local/source/path user@hostname:/public_html/destination_remotefolder
```

For this i get:

> connection to host 'myhost'  port 22 refused.

Please suggest how to transfer via FTP.

If it was an SFTP, i can easily copy from local to remote with above command.

Comment: Please read the `man` pages of the utilities you use. `scp`'s `-i` flag requires an argument. This is a simple usage error.

Comment: Connection refused means you are blocked, most likely by a firewall.

Comment: It is _very_ unlikely that you can access via `FTP` if the system even blocks `ssh` access. About how to use `ftp` within php: please read the documentation. http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Comment: And I am not sure if you understand that `sftp` and `scp` use the same protocol, so address the same `ssh` server. If you cannot connect using `scp` then you can't connect using `sftp`.

Comment: i actually created a free domain, for that im using winscp/filezilla as my FTp, where i need to unzip a zip file to remote...and also i tried without -i..it doesnt work

Comment: can u suggest alternate

Comment: You need an FTP or SSH server to be able to connect your client to it and to transfer the files. Without such server you can try whatever you want to, it won't work. Just as a web browser (clients) needs a http server (web server) to connect to. Without the server, where would the information come from? Such server is a software that runs on the target system and listens for connections. So you will have to install and configure it. And generally: _please_ use an ssh server (so `scp` or `sftp`) and _not_ an ftp server (`ftp protocol`). FTP is a left over from the 1970th. Horrible.

Answer (score 1):

Something I do not understand here: if you are trying to use an FTP server, why do you use scp? scp is basically the cp (copy) command over SSH (Secure SHell)...
SSH and FTP are very different protocols and they are not interchangeable.

You'll see in many places on the internet people advocating for the use of scp instead of FTP, but that implies control over the server machine... if you do not have remote access to the server and only access via an FTP port, then it seems to me what you need is **an FTP client**.

Edit: as far as I know, it is not possible to use the FTP protocol to unzip something **on the remote server** so all you can do, unfortunately, is to unzip the file locally and then use your FTP client to send all the files to the remote server. I don't foresee any problem transferring all the files with FileZilla, besides the time it takes to send a lot of small files...

Comment: Operating an `ftp` server requires exactly the same effort as an `ssh` server does. So why stick with the old, insecure and certainly outdated protocol?

Comment: im using a Filezilla ftp client, need to know how to unzip an archieve to remote

Comment: @arkascha: because you might not have control over the server... When you subscribe for a free (or paying) web server account, very often you get nothing but an FTP access. It is unfortunately not a choice for the user to make in many cases.

Comment: @NadiaCerezo Whilst that is unfortunately true I would strongly suggest to think twice whether one really wants to make a contract with a service provider that still uses such an old and outdated protocol. There are alternatives, time has moved on.

Comment: @arkascha I would invite you then to provide a list of web servers with SSH access you recommend... I, for one, have found it difficult to find the right combination of protocols and technologies at an affordable price. It is certainly a shame that SSH access is such a rare feature in the field, when it is so obvious, but still that is not the users' fault.